# How can I monitor video memory usage?

Tags: video, display, memory

How can I monitor video memory usage?

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system you are interested in monitoring the usage from? Also, knowing what make/model of video adapter may be useful as well. :)

Comment: I'm using windows 7, mainly.

Comment: `make/model of video adapter` how can I know this?

Comment: You can check it via the `dxdiag` utility.

Comment: The GPU is graphics card specific so there won't be a general tool that monitors this. Look for something specific to your graphics card.

Answer (score 33):

GPU load monitoring is not a built-in feature in Windows, but there are third-party tools to do the job.

[GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) is a graphics card information tool that supports a number of monitoring options for graphics cards such as clock speeds, fan speed, memory load, GPU load and Video Engine load.

I believe it supports both ATI (AMD) and nVidia graphics cards.

This is a screen shot of my system while playing a h.264 video.

[image]

Comment: For my model it only shows the Clocks, not the load

Comment: your pic showed quite a lot of info. I circled the part I think you were getting at. Was that the part you were getting at?

Comment: @JaderDias it works for my intel hd graphics 4000 in my laptop. What model is yours?

Comment: What about for Linux?

Comment: @AaronFranke https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=gpu-z+linux

Answer (score 8):

If you use an ATI or NVIDIA card, you should check out [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).

> **Main Features**:
>
> - Support NVIDIA and ATI cards
> - Displays adapter, GPU and display
>   information
> - Displays overclock, default clocks
>   and 3D clocks (if available)
> - Validation of results
> - No installation required
> - Support for Windows 2000 / XP / Vista
>   / Windows 7 (both 32 and 64 bit
>   versions are supported)

[image]

[image]

Comment: so much info there, you should circle the relevant part

Answer (score 7):

[AMD System Monitor](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/gpu-100) is pretty good.  It gives you % CPU and GPU utilization.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The Windows 10 task manager now has some nice GPU stats, including memory, although you can not quite see it in this image. https://www.howtogeek.com/351073/how-to-monitor-gpu-usage-in-the-windows-task-manager/

[image]

I've also used Process Explorer to measure GPU, although the latest Windows 10 updates seem to have broken that ability.

Answer (score 4):

You can monitor NVidia GPUs with [RivaTuner](http://downloads.guru3d.com/RivaTuner-v2.09-download-163.html)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) (a tool similar to RivaTuner) can show this in real-time on a graph, among other things. Note that it does not require a MSI card.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All for one: You could use http://openhardwaremonitor.org/

But it will not give you the "Number" of used Memory, but in percent!
Also a lot of more, usefull infos ;)

EDIT: Ignore the Answer! OHM supports Memory Usage and not only this...
You will get the Usage in Percent. The Memory Usage in Size is little bit tricky, but possible! I would give you the code, when needed!

EDIT #2: https://github.com/DarthDestroyer/openhardwaremonitor has implemented the Memory Usage in Numbers for Nvidia GPUs