# How to monitor GPU load on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, performance-monitor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I monitor video memory usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/160291/how-can-i-monitor-video-memory-usage)

Performance monitor can bring CPU, Mem, HD and Network usage. Where is the GPU load monitor?